# Differentiating between OpenVPN clients using the same certificates

Tags: linux, openvpn, certificate, ip-address

I have a relatively large subset of OpenVPN clients, populating the virtual network of `10.131.0.0/16`. These clients are fairly similar in setup, and therefore use the same certificate.

Is there method for differentiating between these so that they can have a static IP, despite having the same CommonName from the same certificate? Either via a client-side config option, or some other method that does not require a separate certificate for each client.

Using OpenVPN 2.3.4 on Debian for both server and client.

Comment: Nope. OpenVPN uses the CN to differentiate between clients and nothing else.

Comment: @Lenniey not *quite:* 1) there's a config knob which allows multiple instances of the clients using the same CN to connect; 2) it's possible to use two-factor auth -- when the client is required to provide a login and a matching passphrase for instance, and this can be used to performa query against, say, LDAP. I'm afraid that's the only working way to differentiate between the clients using the same certificate.

Comment: Still, if you have a way to regenerate and redeploy the certs on your clients, just do that: it's way more robust as it allows denying access to individual clients by revoking their certs by updating your CA's CRL (which OpenVPN should be told to consult).

Comment: @kostix 1) would be `duplicate-cn`, I presume? That's true, but you can't use that to differentiate between clients. 2) sounds handy, but isn't this outside the scope of OpenVPN itself?

Comment: Simply add login/password authentication to OpenVPN server config.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy and then you can extract the login-data from OpenVPN? Or from the logs? Neat, didn't know that! Sadly, I have no testing VPN server to check this out atm.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy In other words, the username will override CommonName from the cert?

Comment: No. Before all the server checks certificate validation, then creates protected channel, then receives login and password via the protected channel, then checks login/password validation via PAM module (login/password of local users on the server OS).There isn't any link between CN names and logins.

Comment: If you have access to 2nd layer (tap), you can use DHCPd instead OpenVPN for address/route distribution. Having many unconfigured constantly broadcasting devices in /16 smells bad though.